# Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account

Tags: support, post-ban

**I hope this is the right place to ask this question.** I have been trying to ask a question in OS but am unable to do so...

1. This is not a temporary thing since it has been that way for more than 90 days...
2. **Also I have checked my answers/questions** and actually went trough all my stats
   and found nothing special. I got one down vote on some answer but that I think is
   only natural.
3. **Also I am not working on a network computer** and only login from my current account which is an active account on wordpress.stackexchange.com

I have no idea what might be the reason I got banned...
Must I create a fake new account to be a member?

Is there anything I can do? Why did this happen?

Comment: Did you delete any of your posts recently?

Comment: No, don't create a fake account. You will get caught. I'm assuming you did read the full content of the link in your ban message?

Comment: And you say *"I have been trying to ask a question in OS"*... I assume you mean SO?

Comment: @Bart I thought the same when I was editing, but thought it best not to assume. Considered it could've been OnStartups (or some OS-related site I'm not familiar with), but now that I've seen the use's account list, I'm guessing it is SO.

Comment: @Jim Yeah, so that's why I asked for clarification. Especially since there is not a lot of visible activity on his SO account...

Comment: yee i meant SO ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Our usual advice is that you should improve your existing posts and contribute in positive ways on the site in order to have this (automatic) ban lifted.

It looks like your account was basically right on the edge. One of those cases that Shog9 describes [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146436/155160).

I've reviewed your questions and upvoted one of them, so now you're no longer blocked from asking.

However, you are still on that edge. Keep the suggestions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) in mind when posting to avoid triggering this ban again in the future.

Comment: thanks a lot anna ;) - i would read the attached links thoroughly and would try to make the time to answer some questions to better stabilize my user credentials. Cheers, Sagive

Comment: @SagiveSEO Good luck. :)